# Eclipse - Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Looking at other questions that are similar, the error i am  receiving is sometimes due to an Eclipse bug. However, since i am a novice, this may not be the case.

**The error:**

```
Values cannot be resolved to a type
```

**The code:**

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.bNewStory:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddStory.class));
    case R.id.bAddTopic:
        CustomDialogClass cdd=new CustomDialogClass(Values.this); //ERROR OCCURS
        cdd.show();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Already tried restarting Eclipse
- Already tried cleaning project
- Package has been declared

Comment: There is nothing in your code which indicate that Values.this should be a type.

Comment: By the way, what is `Values`?

Comment: I was following the top answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

It is meant to be a reference to an activity so i can show a custom dialogue.

Comment: in that case change Values to MainActivity and it should compile correctly

Comment: post your whole activity

Comment: Do you have an Activity named Values?

Comment: Thank you, it was due to the incorrect naming of an activity.